# Save the Easter bunny - An Enigmatic puzzle

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, story, seasonal

*This is a puzzle themed for Easter Monday 17-04-17*

The inhabitants of Puzzletopia are shocked: the Easter bunny has gone missing! They immediately ask you, the police’s *best* detective, to find out where he is!

You found the following clues:
The Easter bunny has visited only 3 houses. The fourth house had one egg hidden. You find footprints and follow them professionally.
The person walked to the end of the street. There you find a note. It reads:

```
SECOND STREET, FROM CLUESTREET      $  2,99
SECOND STREET, FROM CLUESTREET      $  2,99
------------------------------------------- +
TOTAL COST                          $  5,98
BUS CARD BONUS                     -$  0,00
------------------------------------------- +
TOTAL (INCLUDING TAX)               $  5,98
TOTAL TO PAY                        $  6,00

82 101 99 101 105 118 101 100 32 105 116 44
32 74 97 99 107 63

CLUEDRIVER TRANSPORT - CDT, AT YOUR SIDE!
```

[image: LOGO]
`TICKET ID:` [image: This is a barcode! Wow!]
`MOBILE   :` [image: barcode]

`VISIT US :   CIPHERLANE 3, PUZZLETOPIA (ZIPCODE: 4e6f70-65)`

You immediately rush to Second Street. There you see more footprints. After following them for a while, you get suspicious and check the footprint. It’s a different footprint. Unless...

**Where is the Easter bunny? Who kidnapped him, and what is the henchman called?**

Comment: There might be some incorrectly encrypted messages. If you think you found one, please comment or fit the question in your answer, if you need to share information.

Comment: For the sequence of numbers, it should be "82 101 99 101 105..." instead of "82 101 99 105 101..."

Comment: I fixed it, it was just a typo. Not part of puzzle.

Comment: Might have found a typo, see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The numbers on the bottom of the receipt mean

> "Received it, Jack?" when converted from decimal to ascii

The mobile qr code says

> Click Me

Which leads to

> A qr code that says:
>  Puzzletopia Puzzle You find some hex code: 546578742061626f76652077617320746f206d69736c6561642074686f73652064616d6e656420636f70732e2049206c65667420612067757920746865726520746f206b656570207468656d20627573792eaa49276d2064726f7070696e6720796f752061743aa486964656f7574204176656e75652c20333935a536565206d652074686572652eaa596f757220667269656e642042656e2c2064726976696e672074686973206275732e

Which means

> Text above was to mislead those damned cops. I left a guy there to keep them busy.ªI'm dropping you at:¤FV÷WBfVçVRÂ3ZSee me there.ªYour friend Ben, driving this bus.
> when converted to ascii.
> "¤FV÷WBfVçVRÂ3Z" is "a486964656f7574204176656e75652c20333935a" in hexadecimal. Removing the first and last character and converting the result (486964656f7574204176656e75652c20333935) to hexadecimal results in "Hideout Avenue, 395". This could be a typo since several other characters also seem incorrect. "Text above" could be referring to the bar-code, which leads to a dead end.

So

> The easter bunny is at 395 Hideout Avenue, Ben "kidnapped" the easter bunny, and the henchman is called Jack.